# jQuery - just bind an event one time

Tags: jquery

I'm having a lot of trouble in binding an event to an element when another event from a different element is triggered.
My HTML is a textbox that when some text is added it creates a contextual menu with suggerences. Since this menu is a dynamically created table and I want to bind a click event to its  elements. So, this is my code:

```js
$("#TextBox").on("keypress", function(e) {
    $("#Menu").find("td").on("click", function(event) {     
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault(); 
        processText(event, $(this).children().text()); 
    });
    $(this).off(e);
});
```

But, I don't know why, it doesn't work. Also, I've tried creating a variable and use it as a flag, but doesn't work either.

If I just don't unbind it, the click event is triggered as many times as the user pressed a key. But I want to unbind it so it's executed only one time.

**EDIT**: The error was that I was handling the incorrect event. I had to handle "keyup" because in "keypress" the table still didn't exist.

Comment: You're attaching a new `click` event for each `td` on each keypress (without removing the old)... this is *almost* definately not what you want. You should only need to bind it once *outside* the `keypress` handler.

Answer (score 4):

If you really only want the event to fire once, you can bind with $.one().

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using the `on` function. Use the alternate version (for delegation of event handling) of on to bind event handlers to dynamically added elements:

Use the on function as follows:

```
$("#TextBox").on("keypress", function(e) {
    $(this).off("keypress");
});

$("#Menu").on("click", "td", function(event) {     
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault(); 
        processText(event, $(this).children().text()); 
});
```

Check this link for more info: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: But I can't do that because $("#Menu") still doesn't exist, it is created dynamically when the user presses a key in the textbox.

Comment: @Kits89: When you create the Menu item is there a specific element that you are appending it to if not change the delegate to `$("body").on("click", "#Menu td", function(event) {   `

Comment: +1 Thank you. I edited with the solution, it was my fault, sorry!